# Referencing a class from a different folder in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I move my classes into different folders to organize them;how do I reference classes from other folders I.E. I have SkypeFX.java in the /src/ folder and Threads.java in the /src/Misc/ folder.

[image]

Comment: didn't you try importing those missing classes by package names?

Comment: Since you're using [tag:intellij-idea], always move classes using refactor/move so that other classes that reference the moved class get updated.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to move classes in Intellij Idea, you should always use [Move Refactorings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/move-refactorings.html?origin=old_help).

If you do so, Idea automatically updates all references to moved files and all references to other files in the moved file. This way you do not have to resolve references manually.

To perform move refactoring you can either:

- Press <kbd>F6</kbd>
- On the **Refactor menu**, or on the context menu, choose **Move**

Comment: It updated everything else fine, but when its not in a folder it chucked a hissy fit.
I fixed it by just putting it its own folder.